# include_relative post.path jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, textile

I'm trying to put a number of related posts on a single page. The problem is that the included posts are all  textile pages, using some {% highlight %} tags. When I try to include then via post.content, they don't get textilized (e.g, I see "{% highlight..." on the page).

I've tried a few different things:

This never gets textilized:

```
{% for post in site.tags.my_tag %}
{{ post.content | textilize }}
{% endfor %}
```

This (based on http://nateeagle.com/2011/08/31/jekyll-not-parsing-includes/) returns no content:

```
{% for post in site.tags.apidocs %}
{% capture included_post %}
{{% include_relative post.path %}}
{% endcapture %}
{{ included_post | textilize }}
{% endfor %}
```

Any ideas?

Bradley

Comment: For clarity, my goal is for some liquid tags to be executed in the included post, which is a .textile file. The file that includes the content above is also a .textile file.

Comment: One issue I found was that post.path returned "_posts/file.textile", which I don't think is the proper relative path from the current file. I concatenated a ../ to that path, but still no dice.

Comment: I've noticed that if I reference the filename directly (e.g., {% include_relaitve myfile.textile %}, it works perfectly. So I think what I'm looking for here is how to pass the filename to include_relative via a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
{% include_relative {{post.path}} %}
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the include. Alas, realizing that I need to remove the front matter now...

Comment: In case any one else hits this, the full solution involved the following plugin: http://dtsn.me/2013/07/11/remove-front-matter-jekyll-plugin/

plus (with the correction from David):

    {% for post in site.tags.my_tags %}
    {% capture included_post %}
    {% include_relative {{post.path | replace: '_posts/',''}} %}
    {% endcapture %}
    {{ included_post | removefrontmatter }}
    {% endfor %}